# SpellCheck overwrite in entire wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way how i can overwrite in my entire application the spellcheck. I know how i can do it on the single properties but not in my entire application.My goal is If a language pack is not installed i want to disable the spellcheck in my entire application. At the moment it is sometimes enabled and sometimes disabled.

The reason for that is that the SpellCheck will fail if the required language pack is no installed so i want to check if the language pack is installed on the start and if not disable it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.isenabled?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: So it means i can only change the single control and not all controls in the entire application. I know the side but i wanted to disable it for all controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define an implicit `Style` in `App.xaml` that sets the `SpellCheck.IsEnabled` property to `false`:

```
<Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
    <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

This `Style` will get applied to all `RichTextBox` elements in the application.

If you want to enable spell checking for an individual control, you could just set the property for this one to override the default value set by the `Style`:

```
<RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" />
```